# How to pass parameters to the gtest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

How can I pass parameter to my test suites?

```
gtest --number-of-input=5
```

I have the following main gtest code. And `--number-of-input=5` should be passed to InitGoogleTest().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  std::cout << "Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n";
  ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:hello.xml";
  testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

I don't know how to pass my parameter to the test suites/cases as follows?

```
class TestTwo : public QuickTest {
 protected:
  virtual void SetUp() {
      QuickTest::SetUp();
      square = new Square(10);
      circle = new Circle(10);

  }

  virtual void TearDown() {
      delete square;
      delete circle;
      QuickTest::TearDown();
  }

  Square* square;
  Circle* circle;
};


// Now, let's write tests using the QueueTest fixture.

// Tests the default constructor.
TEST_F(TestOne, DefaultConstructor) {
  EXPECT_EQ(100.0, square->area());
}
TEST_F(TestOne, DefaultDestructor) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1,1);
}
TEST_F(TestOne, VHDL_EMIT_Passthrough) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1,1);
}
TEST_F(TestOne, VHDL_BUILD_Passthrough) {
  EXPECT_EQ(1,1);
}
```

#### Added

I modified the main method to show the argv[i] after `InitGoogleTest()`.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Running main() from gtest_main.cc\n";
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(output) = "xml:hello.xml";
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        cout << i << ":" << argv[i] << endl;
    }
```

This is the arguments given to the gtest: `./s --number-of-input=5 --gtest_filter=Test_Cases1*`.

This is the results:

```
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
0:./s
1:--number-of-input=5
Note: Google Test filter = Test_Cases1*
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

gtest filters out the tests that does not have the name of `Test_Cases1`, and it also shows the correct arguments other than those start with `gtest`.

Reference - [How to run specific test cases in GoogleTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076072/how-to-run-specific-test-cases-in-googletest)

Comment: Here is another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260907/whats-the-way-to-access-argc-and-argv-inside-of-a-test-case-in-google-test-fram

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Google Test only recognizes its own command-line options. Each time it finds one, it removes it from `argv` and updates `argc` accordingly, so after `InitGoogleTest` returns, anything left over in `argv` is available for you to process yourself. Use your favorite command-line-parsing technique, store the results in some global variable, and refer to it during your tests.

If a command-line options *looks like* a Google Test option but really isn't, then the program will print its help message and exit without running any tests. Google Test options start with `gtest_`.

Comment: So what do you do with the left overs to accesss them from inside a TEST()?

Comment: @David, I think the final sentence of my first paragraph answers exactly that.