# What's the way to access argc and argv inside of a test case in Google Test framework?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I’m using Google Test to test my C++ project. Some cases, however, require access to argc and argv to load the required data.

In the `main()` method, when initializing, argc and argv are passed to the constructor of testing.

```
testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
```

How can I access them later in a test?

```
TEST(SomeClass, myTest)
{
  // Here I would need to have access to argc and argv
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters to the gtest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818785/how-to-pass-parameters-to-the-gtest)

Comment: It's not answered however and the answer is posted below, so plz don't close.

Comment: What do you mean "it's not answered"? The answer is right there: "Use your favorite command-line-parsing technique, store the results in some global variable, and refer to it during your tests." Besides, that has nothing to do with whether this should be closed. It's a duplicate question. Once one is closed, the answers can be merged.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know google's test framework, so there might be a better way to do this, but this should do:

```
//---------------------------------------------
// some_header.h
extern int my_argc;
extern char** my_argv;
// eof
//---------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------
// main.cpp
int my_argc;
char** my_argv;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{    
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  my_argc = argc;
  my_argv = argv;
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
// eof
//---------------------------------------------

//---------------------------------------------
// test.cpp
#include "some_header.h"

TEST(SomeClass, myTest)
{
  // Here you can access my_argc and my_argv
}
// eof
//---------------------------------------------
```

Globals aren't pretty, but when all you have is a test framework that won't allow you to tunnel some data from `main()` to whatever test functions you have, they do the job.

Answer (score 1):

If running on Windows using Visual Studio, those are available in __argc and __argv.