# How can I use Google Test to call specific test functions at specific places in the main() function?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, googletest

I am using TDD and Google Test for a project that involves numerical simulations. The state of the data gets changed within a loop in the `main` function, but there are requirements that need to be fulfilled after each change. If all requirements are fulfilled for a test case, the acceptance test passed:

```
while(simulation)
     modify simulation data
     FIRST_TEST()
     some other simulation operations
     SECOND_TEST()
```

The [GTest primer](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Test_Fixtures:_Using_the_Same_Data_Configuration_for_Multiple_Te) states that usually RUN_ALL_TESTS() is called. The [Advanced Guide](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Running_Test_Programs:_Advanced_Options) shows how to run sub-tests, by *filtering out tests* from RUN_ALL_TESTS. However, I would like to know how to invoke tests individually.

Otherwise I would need to write a new acceptance testing application each time I need a new test like FIRST_ and SECOND_ in the pseudocode snippet above.

Some more background: I’m using the OpenFOAM framework for Computational Fluid Dynamics, so creating global fixtures outside of `main` is not an option. The simulation application requires a directory and configuration files to run, and the global objects in main are correlated (require each other for initialization). One example of such an application is  [OpenFOAM-2.2.x](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/blob/master/applications/solvers/multiphase/interFoam/interFoam.C).

#### Further Notes

I took the accepted answer as well as the answer on how to use argc and argv as global variables within the test found on [another question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5262122/735756) and I summarized this into this compile-able small model, maybe someone finds it useful:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <iostream>

class Type 
{
    int value_ = 0;
    int times_ = 1; 

    public: 

        Type(int x) : value_(x) {}; 

        void operator()(){
            if (times_ < 10) {
                ++times_; 
                value_ *= times_; 
            }
        }

        int value () const { return value_; } 
}; 

class mySeparatedTests : public ::testing::Test 
{
    protected:

      template<typename Type>
      void TEST_ONE(Type const &t)
      {
          ASSERT_TRUE((t.value() % 2) == 0); 
      }

      template<typename Type> 
      void TEST_TWO(Type const & t)
      {
          ASSERT_TRUE((t.value() - 5) > 0); 
      }
};

TEST_F(mySeparatedTests, testName)
{
    extern char** globalArgv; 
    char** argv = globalArgv;

    // Simulation parameters and objects requiring argc and argv for initialization. 
    int simulationEndTime;  

    *argv[1] >> simulationEndTime;  

    Type typeObject(*argv[2]); 

    TEST_ONE(typeObject); 

    // Simulation loop. 
    for (int i = 0; i < simulationEndTime; ++i)
    {
        typeObject(); 

        TEST_TWO(typeObject); 
    }
}

int globalArgc; 
char** globalArgv; 

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    globalArgc = argc; 
    globalArgv = argv; 

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS(); 

    return 0; 
}
```

This approach, as described in the accepted answer, ports the simulation code from `main` into TEST_F, and uses the `mySeparatedTests` class functions to define individual tests, that can then be called anywhere. This is compiled with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -l gtest main.cpp  -o main
```

And tests fail/pass depending on parsed parameter pairs;

this fails:

```
./main 1 1
```

this succeeds:

```
./main 2 2
```

**Note:** I’m aware of char/int conversion happening; this is just to show how to pick up args.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have slightly misunderstood what googletest does. The control of the test sequence is controlled by the test runner. What you could do is define a single test with your `while` loop with the difference that your `FIRST_TEST`, etc are functions of a fixture, with some assertions. For example:

instead of:

```
int main(...) { ... while (...) PERFORM_TEST("A"); ... }
TEST(A,some_test) {}
```

you could take the standard googletest runner main and define:

```
// fixture
class MyTest : public ::testing::Test {
protected:
  bool simulation() {
    ///...
  }

  void TEST_A() {
    ASSERT_EQ(...);
    //...
  }

  void TEST_B() {
    ASSERT_EQ(...);
    //...
  }
  ///
};

// the test "runner"
TEST_F(MyTest, main_test) {
  while (simulation()) {
    // modify simulation data
    TEST_A();
    // some other simulation operations
    TEST_B();
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks. One question: the constructor of MyTest is in this case required to initialize the simulation data. Is it possibile for MyTest to take the argc and argv usually parsed by main as parameters?

Comment: you can create a singleton argc/argv memento copy before you initialize googletest in your [custom main](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_7_Primer#Writing_the_main()_Function) - before `::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv); return RUN_ALL_TESTS();` and accessing it from your fixture constructor. Maybe you'd want to move test definitions into textfiles like JSON or XML, but better try not to depend on external data (+ see [vpt](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_7_AdvancedGuide#Value_Parameterized_Tests))

Comment: thanks. I cannot move the test definitions, I am working with legacy code that has 1.5 million lines, and uses a standardized input/output system of configuration and input files. since I am extending this, I want to test my extensions within the legacy framework, with minimal modifications to the workflow/config. I've used the argc, argv as global data, since the framework does that already. I'll post what I got from your answer in my question + accept your answer shortly.