# Is it possible to envoke Boost.UnitTest tests within main in a way similar to the Boost.MinimalTestFacility?

Tags: c++, boost-test

I am extending a library for computational fluid dynamics, so I am dealing with legacy code. The applications involve initializing sometimes very large objects, most of which are codependent. The initialization is dependent on configuration and input files stored in a directory.

Trying to use a testing framework compared to my own testing hacked libs should make sense, since there are various test cases and families, and tests, and I could benefit from having the test tree and shiny reports + ability to automatize the tests.

However, I heve encountered a problem when trying to call specific tests *at specific points* in the program. This problem has occured already when I tried using Google Test - see [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21310067/735756)

Here is a model of the problem using Boost.Test:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE hugeObjectEvenTest 
#define BOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include<random>
#include<iostream>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE (hugeObjectEvenTest) 

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE (test1)
{
    BOOST_CHECK(hugeObject.value() % 2 == 0);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

class HugeClass
{
    int value_ = 0; 

    public:

        HugeClass() = default; 

        HugeClass(int x) : value_(x) {}; 

        int value () { return value_; }

        void setValue (int val) { value_ = val; }
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    HugeClass hugeObject; 

    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e1(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        hugeObject.setValue(dist(e1));  
        std::cout << hugeObject.value() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is merely a model of a numerical solver application, like the one found [here](https://github.com/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-2.2.x/blob/master/applications/solvers/multiphase/interFoam/interFoam.C).

What I *think* I need is a global fixture, that is able to take a reference to the `hugeObject`.

The instances just like `hugeObject` are modified (modeled with random number generation) during the simulation, within the simulation loop (modeled with the for loop).

All I want to do, is to execute specific tests at specific points within main, and benefit from having a test tree, and all the other perks of using a testing framework. Something similar to the functionality of the [Minimal Test Facility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/minimal.html).

Is this at all possible with Boost.Test? Like Google Test, selecting specific tests can be done by [parsing during execution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html). This is of no use whatsoever for my problem. I have used both GTest and BoostTest for unit tests, where the initialization of fixtures is local and not dependent on main (argc, argv, configuration and input files), and I had no problems.

Edit: I will get flamed for this probably, but when dealing with legacy code, I believe it would be beneficial to somehow be able to access the objects in main via const refs (to ensure that the tests don't modify objects), in a simpler way than inheriting from fixture classes. In my case, doing that means a day of work, compared to simple BOOST_TEST_REQUIRE placed within main when using the minimal testing framework. Of course, with the minimal framework I have no test tree, etc, so I am back where I started: at my own hacked test lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to do this is to perform your own manual test registration, separate the tests you want to execute together into suites and run them manually. For example:

```
using namespace boost::unit_test;

void test1() { std::cout << "Running test 1\n"; }
void test2() { std::cout << "Running test 2\n"; }
void test3() { std::cout << "Running test 3\n"; }

void init_test_tree() {

    test_suite *ts1 = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "suite_a");
    ts1->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &test1 ) );
    ts1->add(BOOST_TEST_CASE( &test2 ));
    framework::master_test_suite().add(ts1);

    test_suite *ts2 = BOOST_TEST_SUITE( "suite_b");
    ts2->add( BOOST_TEST_CASE( &test3 ) );
    framework::master_test_suite().add(ts2);
}

bool empty_init() { return true; }

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    init_test_tree();

    std::cout << "Run suite a\n";
    framework::run( framework::master_test_suite().get("suite_a"));

    std::cout << "Run suite b\n";
    framework::run( framework::master_test_suite().get("suite_b"));

    std::cout << "Run the tree\n";
    // pass empty initialization function as we've already constructed the test tree
    return unit_test_main(&empty_init, argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I still don't see how the test{1..3} functions are accessing objects initialized in main.

Comment: In this example they aren't, however it's not difficult to initialize the test suites with fixtures when you build the test tree. Use the `BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE` macro instead of `BOOST_TEST_SUITE`. See also the examples in the boost test source distribution.

Comment: OK thanks a lot, I'll give it a go right now. I'm asking first, because I will be packing up object initialization for at least few hours. :)

Answer (score 0):

Registering your own test cases manually is tedious, boring and error-prone and I don't recommend it.  Instead, you can simply define your own `main()` instead of having Boost.Test provide it for you.  Write a `main` that looks like this:

```
HugeClass hugeObject; 

boost::unit_test::test_suite *init_function(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // create test cases and suites and return a pointer to any enclosing
    // suite, or 0.
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e1(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,100); 

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        hugeObject.setValue(dist(e1));  
        std::cout << hugeObject.value() << std::endl;
    }
    return boost::unit_test::unit_test_main(init_function, argc, argv);
}
```

If you do this, you get:

- Automatic test case registration
- Use of test suites
- The ability to do any special stuff first in `main()` before any part of Boost.Test runs

One annoying side-effect of writing your own main: the signature for the init_function is different depending on if you linked with the static version of Boost.Test or the shared library (dynamic) version of Boost.Test.  The differences are discussed in my [Boost.Test documentation rewrite](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/index.html) in the sections on the [static library](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/test/guide/compilation/static_library.html) and the [shared library](http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/test/guide/compilation/shared_library.html).