# Testing Functions at runtime using GTest

Tags: qt, googletest

I have a GUI application in Qt. I am testing it with the help of GTEST.

There are some functions that I want to check at run time i.e based on button clicks am I getting the expected output. As far as I have understood we cannot have multiple calls of RUN_ALL_TESTS() as it will cause irrelevant tests to run too.

Is there any way I can cause Tests to run only when a specific event is received by the application?

Can some one please help me with this?

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by running irrelevant tests? Do you want to run a specific test when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes I want a specific test to run when a button is pressed.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076072/how-to-run-specific-test-cases-in-googletest