# How to run a specific unit test using "make" with cmake

Tags: cmake, gnu-make, googletest

I have a C++ project built using CMake. Following is what I do to build it.

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake .. && make
```

`make test` runs all the unit tests which are built [gtest](https://github.com/google/googletest).

Given that I have a test like below, how can I run only one specific test?

```
// This is MyClassAPI_test.cpp
TEST(MyClassAPI_test, MyClassAPITest) {
    EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

I tried running

> make check TESTS='MyClassAPI_test'

but it does not work?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what autotools has to do with your issue. Also, are you missing a `cd build` in your build commands? Or are you actually running the `cmake` command from outside the `build` directory?

Comment: The command you tried is the correct way to do it if you are using autotools to generate the makefile, but it seems you're using cmake instead. With a makefile generated by cmake it will be completely different and you should check out the cmake manual.

Comment: [how-to-run-specific-test-cases-in-googletest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076072/how-to-run-specific-test-cases-in-googletest) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cmake, `make test` uses ctest executable behind.

To launch only the wanted test, from build directory use this command: `ctest -R MyClassAPI_test`

For further info, see : [testing-using-ctest](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Testing%20With%20CMake%20and%20CTest.html#testing-using-ctest)