# How to run TEST functions in Google Test API

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I am following this tutorial, but I dont entirely understand how the TEST functions are executed

https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/google_unit_test_gtest.php

The example code is here:

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "simplemath.h"

TEST(testMath, myCubeTest)
{
    EXPECT_EQ(1000, cubic(10)); 
}
```

Does the `TEST` function get called automatically by the API?
What if there are multiple `TEST` functions?

I have some external code which has multiple `TEST` functions and I need to call them from another executable outside of GTest. I was able to include the project, but cannot figure out how to call the `TEST` functions.

Is there any way that I can call `TEST` manually from another piece of code?

I see that `TEST` is defined as `GTEST_TEST` in gtest.h
But I don't see where `GTEST_TEST` is defined.
Where is the `main` function? Is it somewhere in `gtest` api?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write `main`. From [docs](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#writing-the-main-function):

> Most users should not need to write their own main function and instead link with gtest_main (as opposed to with gtest), which defines a suitable entry point.

But you can filter, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26461698/980129).

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    ::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "Test_Cases1*";
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

You'll get more options on that answer.